# Oracle SQL SELECT does not work

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this SELECT in Oracle:

```
SELECT
     po.id, po.name
FROM 
     poffice po
WHERE 
po.id not in 
(
    select distinct 
        poffice_id 
    from pdistrict
);
```

which does not return any values.
BUT the next code returns some records.

```
SELECT
   po.id, po.name
FROM
    poffice po
    LEFT JOIN pdistrict pd 
    ON po.ID = pd.poffice_id
WHERE pd.ID IS NULL;
```

Could anybody explain WHY? Where I'm wrong?

Comment: are you sure with "po.id not in" ?

Comment: I guess the aim is to find postoffices which have undefined district values

Comment: Do you have `null` values in `poffice_id`?

Comment: The second WHERE clause should be as "WHERE pd.poffice_id IS NULL;" according to first query to make a correct comparison

Comment: Can you share the table values? It would be so much easier to get a valid answer.

Comment: Thanks to all! This issue occurs because I have some NULL poffice_id

Comment: SELECT
     po.id, po.name
FROM 
     poffice po
WHERE 
po.id not in 
(
    select distinct 
        poffice_id 
    from pdistrict WHERE poffice_id IS NOT NULL
);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you have a record in `PDISTRICT` where  `POFFICEID` is null. If this is the case, the semi-join with `NOT IN` will not work.

Your second query is equivalent to this one (assuming `poffice.id` is not nullable):

```
SELECT po.id, po.name
  FROM poffice po
 WHERE po.id NOT IN (SELECT poffice_id 
                       FROM pdistrict 
                      WHERE pofficed_id IS NOT NULL);
```

Comment: With `DISTINCT` please

Comment: @DennisS. The `DISTINCT` is not necessary: if an element is not in a set, it will therefore not be in the deduplicated set. The `DISTINCT` keyword is ignored by the optimizer. IMO it is redundant and doesn't improve readability

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is correct, the problem is `not in`.  If *any* value returned by the subquery is `NULL`, then no rows are returned.  This is why I strongly recommend *always* using `not exists` rather than `not in` with a subquery:

```
SELECT po.*
FROM poffice po
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM pdistrict pd WHERE pd.poffice_id = po.id);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retrieve the office which don't have po.id then you can use simple select query with null condition.

```
 SELECT
     po.id, po.name
FROM 
     poffice po
WHERE 
po.id is NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

The two queries you posted do different things, thus you get different results.

In the first query, you're looking for `POFFICE` rows whose `ID` field does not match the `POFFICE_ID` field of any row in the `PDISTRICT` table.

In the second query, you're looking for `POFFICE` rows whose `ID` field either:

1. matches the `POFFICE_ID` field on a row in the `PDISTRICT` table, where the `PDISTRICT.ID` field is NULL, -or-
2. does not match the `POFFICE_ID` field on any row in the `PDISTRICT` table.

So - two different queries, two different results.

Best of luck.